# Does the idea that saving someone's life makes you responsible for them have any real philosophical roots, or is it merely a Hollywood trope?

Tags: ethics, eastern-philosophy, death

I have heard this idea before: if you save a person's life, then forever after, you will be responsible for them.  The only references I can find to this concept are vague claims that it is an Asian concept, and that it was once referenced in an episode of [Kung Fu](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068093/).

However, I find the concept very interesting.  Is this a part of, or result of, a specific philosophy?  Is there documented discussion elaborating on this idea?  Or is it merely an amusing fiction created by Hollywood?

Comment: I think the Philosophy community is taking umbrage to citing a Hollywood plot device as "Philosophy" when the only reference you can find is from from a 35-year old episode of Kung Fu.

Comment: He is asking for more references or for an answer that says with certainty "no it has no philosophical origins", and a downvote without comment is neither.

Comment: The only thing worse than downvotes without comments are comments that whine about downvotes. Downvotes are anonymous for a reason. You aren't forced to leave a comment. Please don't try to guilt people into forgoing that anonymity. If they thought they could add something positive, they would have left a comment of their own accord. The system already reminds them to do so. They obviously chose not to.

Comment: @Beofett: My comment meant no personal offense, and it's difficult to imagine how you've construed it that way. I don't understand what you think the hypocrisy is, or in what way I've violated community standards. I didn't make the argument that you haven't tried to improve the question. That's quite clearly reflected by the edit history. But I very much take offense at your original comment, chastising those who downvoted your question without a comment. They're under no obligation to do so: *that's* the community norm. And trying to guilt them into doing so is "rude and unconstructive".

Comment: Your comment explicitly associates the idea of "common courtesy" with the action of leaving a comment for each and every downvote that you cast. That's not what downvotes are for. You're not meant to take them personally, and they're meant to be anonymous. I feel like I made that clear in my original comment. In my experience, harassing people to justify their downvotes as you've done here negatively affects the community. But that's my personal opinion. I don't speak for the Stack Exchange network or anyone else. A "moderator" title doesn't mean that I'm not allowed to have my own opinions.

Comment: @Cody So you're saying you can't possibly understand how someone could construe a comment that they are "whining" and doing the worst possible thing ("the only thing worse than"), and then telling them to "get on with your life" (nice retcon, btw) as being offensive? Yes, you are allowed to have your own opinions, but you are also supposed to police rude or unconstructive content, not contribute to it, unless I totally misunderstand the role of a moderator. Additionally, I do not "explicitly" associate the idea that "each and every" downvote needs a comment. However, when there are multiples

Comment: The point is, I find your implication that people who downvote posts without leaving a comment are violating "common courtesy" to be more harmful to the community. I don't know what a "retcon" is, and no, I don't understand how you took *personal* offense to the comment. And of course by "the only thing worse than...", I meant "worse for the community". Had I known that someone was going to scrutinize my words so carefully (and had I had about a 1000 character limit) I'd have added some additional ones for clarification. But this discussion obviously isn't going anywhere: my point is clear.

Comment: -cont: the generally accepted "ideal" is for at least some of them to provide some feedback by which the question or answer can be improved. As it was, I did get some feedback (after complaining about the lack of comments), and did improve the question multiple times *as a direct result of the few comments that were left*. The hypocrisy I was referring to, btw, is "whining about the whining", or harassing me because you felt I was "harassing people to justify their downvotes".

Comment: @Cody If you found my comment to be "violating common courtesy", then the appropriate thing to do would be to... flag the comment as rude or offensive. Or, since you are ostensibly a moderator, you could delete it as not constructive. Instead, you chose to make additional comments to berate me. "Retcon", incidentally, refers to editing your comment to remove one of the particularly inflammatory and unnecessary comments ("Get on with your life") to make your claim that you don't understand how I could be *personally* offended by the comment you removed.

Comment: Dude, I made one comment to express my opinion, and one that's pretty common (in my personal experience) across the Stack Exchange network. I've provided what I think is a pretty sufficient explanation of my position, and why I didn't mean it to be personally offensive towards you. Notice that it wasn't directed @Beofett. I didn't flag it as rude/offensive or simply delete it because I thought the opportunity better to make a more general statement about the nature of downvotes. The "additional comments" I've made came about at feeling forced to defend myself and my actions...

Comment: @Cody And I've provided what I think is a pretty sufficient explanation for my position, and why, despite what you *intended*, your comment came off as rude. Yet all you've done is tell me why I'm "wrong", and stealth edit your comment to make it seem like you were less rude and contentious than you really were.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is clear that no-one in society would have an interest in there being such a convention.

- On the one hand, anyone who thought that they might someday need saving wouldn't favor the policy, since it could mean at the moment of danger that a potential saver would feel inhibited from actually doing the saving, out of concern about the burden arising from the extra responsibility that the policy entails. Thus, before or even during the moment of danger, the would-be saved person, worrying that they might not get saved, would prefer society to abandon the policy.
- On the other hand, a person who just wants to save another person's life at that moment wouldn't want to be burdened with the extra responsibility of looking after them forever onwards, and hence would also prefer to abandon the policy.

A more logical policy, perhaps, and one which also sometimes appears in the popular culture venues you mention, calls in contrast for the saved person to have some lifelong duty towards the saver.

Comment: And the converse idea of a life duty or debt has a long tradition in many cultures, notably many ancient greek tragedies draw their tragic consequences from such a debt.

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like a false dichotomy that stems from improper inversion of the 'opposite' concept that not saving somebody's life if you have the chance to makes you responsible for his death.

So, looks more like typical Hollywood fiction.